# Second monitor not detected

Tags: debian, xfce, amd-graphics

I'm using Debian Buster, XFCE 4.12 as my DE, with an [AMD RX 580](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580) graphics card.

I have my primary monitor plugged on an HDMI port, and I wanted to use a secondary monitor on the DVI port, but this one is not detected.

At startup, the boot text is mirrored on both monitors, but at the lightdm greeter, only my primary monitor is on.

When I go to **Settings > Display**, only my primary monitor is detected

Only that display is detected by xrandr as well.

Additional info

```
lshw -c video
```

outputs

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Polaris 20 XL [Radeon RX 580 2048SP]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: ef
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe93ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

And for xrandr

```
xrandr
```

outputs

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      0.00* 
   1440x900       0.00  
   640x480        0.00
```

And info about the OS and the kernel

```
uname -a
```

outputs

```
Linux debian-prout 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5 (2019-06-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I suspect it is a problem with my drivers, but I can't figure out how to install/update them properly yet. I can see some text related to amdgpu firmware when I boot, but it's too fast I can't catch it.

What should I fix?

Comment: @K7AAY your link redirects me to a "Download Not Complete" page, but I finally managed to make it work, not even sure how I did it, I'll post details as an answer

Comment: Are you using this driver, or something else? https://www.amd.com/en/support (new driver link)  I don't see a Debian-specific driver; Ubuntu is as close as I can find. Also, what happens if you boot with only the DP monitor connected, then add the HDMI after it finishes booting?

Comment: @K7AAY I only used drivers from the debian repositories, a little more detailed in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somehow managed to make it work.

I tried installing some drivers I may need, like `xserver-xorg-video-ati` as I already had `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` installed, and at the end of the installation, I had a lot of warning messages saying that some files starting with `vega20` were missing in `/lib/firmware/amdgpu`

I was able to find and download the files from [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amdgpu) and copied them to said directory.

```
-rw-r--r--  vega20_asd.bin  78336   logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_ce.bin   9344    logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_me.bin   17536   logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_mec.bin  268048  logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_mec2.bin 268048  logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_pfp.bin  21632   logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_rlc.bin  32052   logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_sdma.bin 17408   logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_sdma1.bin    17408   logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_smc.bin  262912  logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_sos.bin  166800  logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_uvd.bin  379328  logstatsplain
-rw-r--r--  vega20_vce.bin  165408  logstatsplain
```

After a reboot, only the monitor on the DVI port was active and found by `xrandr` and the display settings, but then, I checked the `Configure new displays when connected`, unplugged and re-plugged the HDMI output, and I was able to chose whether I wanted to mirror or extend the displays.

And as asked by Paradox in the comment, I only used drivers from the debian package, and the files listed above were manually downloaded and copied to the `/lib/firmware/amdgpu` directory.

Comment: Could you add more details so it could be helpful for others? The name of the installed package, the method,  non-free driver, right?, etc. Did you mean to install the non-free or the free driver (the AMD ones are really good)?Did you install the package `firmware-linux` and/or a driver listed in [Debian wiki]?(https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo)?

Comment: sure, adding the details to the answer right now